# Add custom PHP and HTML to the_content()

Tags: plugins, loop, page-template, the-content

I am developing a wordpress website on the thematic framework.
In my child theme i have made a full width page template called resources.php

In this page template i have written custom php code which displays various custom fields related to posts of a particular category.

For Example :

```
<div class="download">
<ul id="portfolio" class="port">
<?php query_posts(array ( 'category_name' => 'research'   ,  'posts_per_page' => '-1' , 'order'=>'ASC')  ); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li class="<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->category_nicename; echo" ";} ?> resourcelist">
<span class="doctitle"><?php the_field('document_title') ;?> <span class="date"><?php the_field('document_date'); ?></span>  <span class="categry"><?php foreach((get_the_tags()) as $tag) { echo $tag->name; echo" "; } ?></span></span>
<span class="docdes"><?php the_field('document_description') ;?></span>
<span class="docpath"><a title="download" target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('document_path'); ?>">
<img border="0" src="test.png">
</a> </span>


            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Now what i want to do is restrict this page to only users who have registered . 
I have a plugin which takes care of this for eg: page restrict

What page restrict does is it replaces whatever gets called via the page's wisiwyg editor `the_content()` with the message "you need to login".

The page gets blocked however my php code does execute as its a part of the page template.

I am trying to find out a way to add all my php code to `the_content();` so that the output also gets replaced with the message.

I came across this article which gave me the following code.

```
        <?php
        function demo_function( $content ) {

            $someHtml = '<div class="someClass">';
            $someHtml .= 'some text or code goes here';
            $someHtml .= '</div>';

            $filteredcontent = $someHtml . $content;

            return $filteredcontent;
        }
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'demo_function' );
//the loop goes here        
the_content();
    ?>
```

What this code does is that it adds the above HTML within the_content(); 
So, the next time i block the page, even the above content gets blocked. I exactly want that to happen but with my php code not this HTML.

I am really close to cracking this but because of the above syntax appends the html to the variable, I cant append so many lines of my php code via that method.

Please help me. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: what's your question exactly? put what you want to output within the content filter function.

Comment: i want to add my PHP code in the_content .. you are right.

Answer (score 1):

i´m not sure to understand your question, but why not use this logic in your function?

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
    do your stuff PHP and inject in content...
} else {
    return standard content or block it;
}
```

and maybe additional test to limit with `current_user_can( $capability )`, and so on...